# How to change percentile values of for the built in Matlab boxplot function?

Tags: matlab

I have an issue with the use of Matlab R2010b and the `boxplot` function.

With a previous version of Matlab, I did some modifications in boxplot.m file so that I could change the percentile values used. By default, boxplots are built considering the first and third quartile (25th and 75th percentiles) to define whiskers. My interest is to use 10th and 90th percentiles.

I tried every solutions I found on the Internet.

So my question is: Has anyone found a way to change the default values (25th and 75th) of percentiles used by the `boxplot` function of Matlab (R2010b and after)?

Many many thanks!

Comment: Whenever I modify a function that ships with MATLAB, I make a copy of it and prefix it with "my". Thus, my modified functions will not be overwritten in a new install. I suggest you do the same, and re-use the modified 2012a version.

Comment: If you really want to modify the 2012b version, you should fix the subfunction `computeBoxIndices` that starts at line 2106.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not trying to modify R2012b version, but R2010b. The one I managed to modify and that worked was the file from R2009a. But I will try to reuse this one as suggested by Jonas, and I'll keep you noticed.

Comment: If you are sharing these plots with other people, please remember to note that these are non-standard boxplots. People tend to make a lot of assumptions about plots that look familiar and 99.99% of the time boxplots are used to denote the quartiles of the distribution. Your plots won't convey that information so you need to indicate that to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the way `boxplot` display the data/quantiles by modifying the properties of the graphical object (and not modifying the function per se).

Here is a piece of code that will modify the quantiles used for the blue box (initially, the blue box corresponds to the .25 and .75 quantiles, and will change to .1 and .9). The base part of the upper/lower whisker will change accordingly. Please note that the tips of the whiskers are unchanged (they still correspond to 1.5 of the interquartile range). You can change the tips of the whiskers just like we changed their base parts.

```
%%% load some data  
load carsmall  
MPG  = MPG(ismember(Origin,'USA','rows'));  
Origin = Origin(ismember(Origin,'USA','rows'),:)  
Origin(isnan(MPG),:) = [];  
MPG   (isnan(MPG),:) = [];  

%%% quantile calculation  
q = quantile(MPG,[0.1 0.25 0.75 0.9]);  
q10 = q(1);  
q25 = q(2);  
q75 = q(3);  
q90 = q(4);  

%%% boxplot the data  
figure('Color','w');  

subplot(1,2,1);  
boxplot(MPG,Origin);   
title('original boxplot with quartile', 'FontSize', 14, 'FontWeight', 'b', 'Color', 'r');  
set(gca, 'FontSize', 14);  

subplot(1,2,2);  
h = boxplot(MPG,Origin) %define the handles of boxplot  
title('modified boxplot with [.1 .9] quantiles', 'FontSize', 14, 'FontWeight', 'b', 'Color', 'r');  
set(gca, 'FontSize', 14);  

%%% modify the figure properties (set the YData property)  
%h(5,1) correspond the blue box  
%h(1,1) correspond the upper whisker  
%h(2,1) correspond the lower whisker  
set(h(5,1), 'YData', [q10 q90 q90 q10 q10]);% blue box  

upWhisker = get(h(1,1), 'YData');  
set(h(1,1), 'YData', [q90 upWhisker(2)])  

dwWhisker = get(h(2,1), 'YData');  
set(h(2,1), 'YData', [ dwWhisker(1) q10])  


%%% all of the boxplot properties are here  
for ii = 1:7  
   ii  
   get(h(ii,1))  
end
```

And here are the results.

[image]